# Taking logs conditional on values in R data.frame

Tags: r

I have some data and I Need to take the log of them. However I have both some NA values and 0. By default, R makes log(0) = NA, but I need to distinguish between 0 and NA. Therefore I am trying to tell R to compute the log only for values different from zero. I tried several specifications and all of them failed.  `x` is a data.frame of dimensions `N x M`, columns are variables and rows are observations. Something like this

```
x <- cbind(c(3,4,0,0), c(0,5,NA,6),c(0,2,NA,NA))
x <- data.frame(x)
x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    0    0
[2,]    4    5    2
[3,]    0   NA   NA
[4,]    0    6   NA
```

My last trials were

```
x_log <- matrix(NA, dim(x)[1], dim(x)[2])
for (i in 1:dim(x)[1]){
if (x[i,] == 0) { x_log[i,] <- x[i,]}
 else {x_log[i,] <- log(x[i,])}
}
```

I get the following error and warnings

```
Error in x_log[i, ] <- log(x[i, ]) : 
incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (x[i, ] == 0) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (x[i, ] == 0) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I also tried this

```
x_log <- matrix(NA, dim(x)[1], dim(x)[2])
for (i in 1:dim(x)[1])
for (j in 1:dim(x)[2])
{ if (x[i,j] == 0) { x_log[i,j] <- x[i,j]}
 else {x_log[i,j] <- log(x[i,j])}
}
```

and get

```
Error in if (x[i, j] == 0) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Where I am wrong ? Is there another more efficient way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Your `x` in the example you gave, is not a data.frame, but a matrix. So I gave you a solution for a matrix. If you want it for a data.frame, please provide an example which is a data.frame

Comment: @Bob If you force log(0) to be 0, then how to distinguish log(1) with it? Actually, R makes log(0) to -Inf and log(NA) to NA.

Comment: Now `x` is a `data.frame`.
@xb. that's true, but I don't have 1 in my data.

Comment: @Bob If there is any values smaller than one will also make the result unreasonable. Why not avoid it to be safer and better practice?

Comment: @xb. I don't get why the result with `0<x<1` is unreasonable. Still I agree about the safety and the best practice

Comment: @Bob the logarithm of a number smaller than one (>0) is a negative number. So it would not be comparable with log(0) if you force log(0) to be zero.

Comment: @xb. That's true. Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- cbind(c(3,4,0,0), c(0,5,NA,6),c(0,2,NA,NA)) # Your data and output
x <- data.frame(x)
x[!is.na(x) & x > 0] <- log(x[!is.na(x) & x > 0]) # My solution
#        X1       X2        X3
#1 1.098612 0.000000 0.0000000
#2 1.386294 1.609438 0.6931472
#3 0.000000       NA        NA
#4 0.000000 1.791759        NA
```

Comment: This partially worked. However it substitutes 0 with NA. I tried the following `data_log[data_sub == 0] <- data_sub[data_sub==0]` but it doesn't work

Comment: It didn't. see the output, I've added your data set to the answer and anyone can test it and prove me right. Run your code with your data set that you provided in the post. It runs flowless. If you want this code made for a data.frame, please provide another example data with a data.frame (not matrix).

Comment: The code works perfectly with your data.frame. Have you even tried to run it? just run `x[!is.na(x) & x > 0] <- log(x[!is.na(x) & x > 0])` and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

In R: `log(0)==-Inf` instead of `NA`

```
> x <- cbind(c(3,4,0,0), c(0,5,NA,6),c(0,2,NA,NA))
> apply(x,1:2,log)
         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 1.098612     -Inf      -Inf
[2,] 1.386294 1.609438 0.6931472
[3,]     -Inf       NA        NA
[4,]     -Inf 1.791759        NA
```